# Using Python within LaTeX and accessing its variables

Tags: embedding, python

I have used the [`python`](https://bitbucket.org/pmav99/python.sty/src/f89c70d841c9/python.sty) package to include Python in my LaTeX document which works fine.

I am trying to access the Python variables/calculations *outside* of `\begin{python} ... \end{python}`, without luck.

My question is: Can I?  or How do I access variables/calculations within Python code embedded in LaTeX?

Simple example

```
\begin{python}
tdegc = 25.0
tdegf = (tdegc - 32.0)/1.0
print 'T in DegC is ', tdegc , ' in Deg F is ', tdegf
\end{python}
```

My calculations show that `$\mbox{tdegf} = $ tdegf` (this is the value for `tdegf`)

Comment: My experience with this python.sty is limited, but I thought it was only for producing output - it doesn't modify the tex environment outside of the python environment, so there's no way to access these variables.

Comment: I am not 100% clear on your intent. Are you interested in using (say) `\tdegf` in your main document (outside `\begin{python}...\end{python}`) and it should print the equivalent of `\tdegc` in [Fahrenheit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit)? As in `-3.889`? By the way, your Fahrenheit calculation is incorrect: `tdegf = (tdegc - 32.0)*(5/9)`.

Comment: I don't see the reason why the author of the package must be mentioned this explicitly. A link to the package would be much better. I only found a dangling link to the authors former University page.

Comment: Oops - I meant "1.8" (and thanks) - I see what the problem is - the python.sty file is just a way to embed python and not access tex variables

Comment: It is not a way to embed Python, only a way to lay out Python source code within a LaTeX document.

Comment: The python.sty link is broken.

Answer (score 15):

I've played around a little with the [`sagetex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) package (designing tests which can be randomized) and I think you should look into [its documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/sagetexpackage.pdf). `sagetex` allows you incorporate [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) into your LaTeX code. Since Sage is based Python, you can run Python using `sagetex`. There is a `\sage` command that lets you jump back in to work with variables you've defined before, which I think is the issue you are concerned about. You can find [some examples on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sagetex/example.pdf). Here's a cut down sample:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{sagetex} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{sagesilent}%use sage without producing output
n, x = var('n x')
a = ZZ.random_element(-10,10)
while a == 0:
   a = ZZ.random_element(-10,10)
b = ZZ.random_element(-10,10)
c = ZZ.random_element(-10,10)
d = ZZ.random_element(2,9)
ratexp1 = (a*n)/(a*n+1)
ratexp2 = (d**(d*n-1))/((d+1)**n)
ratexp3 = 1/(a*x+b)
deriv1 = diff(ratexp3,x,1)
\end{sagesilent}
\begin{enumerate} %creates the numbering for the problems.
\item $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \sage{ratexp2}$

\vskip 2 in %leaves 2 inches of space for student work
\item Find the derivative of $\sage{ratexp3}$. The answer is $\sage{deriv1}$

\vskip 2 in %leaves 2 inches of space for student work
\item Consider the series: $ \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\sage{ratexp1} $
Find a formula for $s_n$, the nth partial sum. 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The code is choosing random elements for a,b,c,d but throws out a if a=0. I then
defined rational expressions (to be used in the problems) and even calculated a derivative. At that point, I left Sage but I can still access the past work (even in math mode) using the `\sage` command; eg. `\sage{ratexp2}`.

Note: although I used `a = ZZ.random_element(-10,10)` to produce random integers, you can use the typical Python commands to produce random numbers. You'll also need to install Sage, along with the style file. Just like the `python` package, compiling the code produces an intermediate file (`.sage` file) which you process with Sage.
`sagetex` is a very powerful package.

Comment: I will try embedding python into \begin{sagetex} and try to access the variables that way - that may be the solution indeed ... thanks

Comment: @DJP I was wondering if you know if it is possible to use these variable, say your "a" as an argument of a LaTeX command. For example, I tried using a \foreach \n in {1,...,\sage{n}}{whatever here} where n was previously assigned a value in a sageblock environment, but it would not compile. I'm thinking it is because  the way \sage return it's value is different than rather typing a fixed number

Comment: There's some mixing of the Sage and LaTeX variables ( page 5-6 of the documentation link) but not (that I know of) in the way you're asking. Generally, you'd have the \foreach structure coded within the Sage block as a for loop in Python which would then get inserted as a string. Look at my answer for the [Weierstrass function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156993/plotting-weierstrass-function): Sage calculate the points which are then inserted into a LaTeX statement within the sagesilent block: output += r"\draw[blue, thin]...and then put into Latex with the \sagestr command

Comment: My last comment was partially wrong (no Python for loop needed). Inside a sagesilent block there would be something like: output += r"\foreach \n in {1,...,%d}{whatever here}"%(n) where n was the variable. There are various issues that can arise depending on the specifics of "whatever here"; eg, Sage integers and Python Integers are different. It's difficult to say for sure without knowing the specific problem.

Answer (score 11):

There is also `SympyTeX`, a package that allows you to use the complete functionality of python and sympy within your LaTeX document.

Here is an example:
    Using sympy within your LaTeX document is as easy as `$2+2=\sympy{2+2}$`.

```
You can write a block, and then use the variables defined later in your code!
\begin{sympyblock}
    x = sympy.Symbol('x')
    h = sympy.integrate(1+x,x)
\end{sympyblock}
The variable $h$, how can be called using {\verb \sympy{h} }, and you will get $h =  
\sympy{h}$. Similarly, the integral of $1+x^4$ is $\sympy{sympy.integrate(1+x**4,x)}$.
```

This will result in:
[image]

As far as I know it is not yet available on CTAN but you can download it from the author's homepage:
[SympyTeX](http://elec.otago.ac.nz/w/index.php/SympyTeX)

Answer (score 10):

A comparison between all the options.

| package name | LaTeX | CTAN | pers. | sync | 1-run | shell | depython? | engine. | exp. | overleaf | version | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **⟨column header long name⟩** | is it really LaTeX? | is it on CTAN? | persistent variable? | sync | only need a single run? | requires shell escape? | can be converted to a Python-independent TeX document? | Engine independent? | have expandable commands? | works on overleaf? | compatible with which Python version? | additional notes |
| [robust-externalize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712956/250119) | yes | yes | no | yes | yes (*) | optional | yes | yes | no | yes |  | - |
| pyluatex | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | no | no | yes |  |  | - |
| [pythontex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65294/250119) | yes | yes | yes | no | no | no | partially with `depythontex` script | yes | no | [no](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534049/250119) | Python 2.7 or 3.2+ | to insert plots you can use matplotlib `.savefig()` then `\includegraphics` the result, I guess. |
| [sympytex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42761/250119) | yes | yes | yes | no | no | no | can attach the generated `.sout` file with the TeX document | yes | no |  | requires Python 2 | provides `\sympyplot` command to insert a plot; requires sympy package |
| [sagetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33135/250119) | yes | yes | yes | no | no | no | can attach the generated `.sout` file with the TeX document; partially with `makestatic.py` (unmaintained) | yes | no |  |  | provides `\sageplot` command |
| [pythonimmediate](https://ctan.org/pkg/pythonimmediate) (*my package*) | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | yes | no(t yet) | yes | no(t yet) | yes | Python 3 | works without LuaTeX, but commands are unexpandable (for now). Also better debugging/traceback support etc. (see package description) |
| python | yes | yes | no | yes | yes | yes | no | yes | no |  |  | seems unmaintained, incompatible with LuaTeX |
| [Lunatic Python](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42710/250119) | yes | no | yes | yes | yes | yes (required for LuaTeX to load dynamically linked libraries) | no but can be implemented manually | no | yes |  |  | need to install/configure manually, probably the most convenient solution to share data between Lua side and Python side e.g. to use Python callback from Lua? |
| [PyLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305634/250119) | preprocessor output LaTeX | no | yes | yes | yes | no | yes | yes | - |  |  | - |
| [TexSurgery](https://framagit.org/pang/texsurgery) | preprocessor output LaTeX | yes | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | - |  |  | - |
| [hybrid-latex](https://ctan.org/pkg/hybrid-latex) | preprocessor output LaTeX | yes (the .sty file is named pylatex) | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? | - |  |  | - |
| [PlasTeX](https://github.com/plastex/plastex) | no | no | probably yes | yes | yes | no | probably yes | yes | - |  |  | - |
| [Pweave](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132197/250119) | no, it's markdown | no | probably yes | yes | yes | no | - | yes | - |  |  | - |
| (note: have 0 user) [QS-TEX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393165/250119) | preprocessor output LaTeX | no | - | no | no | no | ? | yes | ? |  |  | seems to not have any users at all...? |

of course there's also the ["no package" solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598404/250119) but this one doesn't really count as you can implement anything.

Clarification on some of the columns

- "sync" means that the Python run are interleaved with TeX run. So for example the TeX code following a Python environment only runs after the Python code finishes running.

  if this is false, some other packages use the approach of collecting all the Python code to be run on the first pass, run Python, then re-run LaTeX with the result.
- "single run" means you only need to run LaTeX once. (maybe a few more times to resolve reference, but the Python feature does not require that)
- "persistent variable" means the Python variables from one Python code block can be reused in subsequent Python code blocks.
- "depython" means whether it's possible to modify the document so that it's compilable on machines without Python. "partially" means it's possible for some subset of "well-behaved" documents.
- actually "shell escape" doesn't really matter, as Python code can execute arbitrary system shell command anyway. So if you want to compile untrusted code that use this feature you need to sandbox the Python process as well
- "engine independent" means it can run on all of pdflatex/xelatex/lualatex. Otherwise it only runs on lualatex

(*): `robust-externalize` is single-run if shell-escape is enabled.

sympytex/sagetex requires sympy/sage to be installed correspondingly.

Note, I don't necessarily have experience on many packages here, I only check the manual for how it should be invoked etc.

Comment: .note. a hack to get sympytex to work on overleaf (basic feature at least https://gist.github.com/user202729/34c1243cf3f612332dad60760054c3ed)

Comment: There's also codebraid but it works with Markdown of pandoc instead of LaTeX.

Comment: How to get your package `pythonimmediate` working under `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Krantz The package is supported on PDFLaTeX. To avoid cluttering the comment area maybe move to chat or https://github.com/user202729/pythonimmediate-tex/discussions ?

Comment: Awesome comparison! I just added an answer based on `robust-externalize`, as far as I see it fulfills all boxes.

Answer (score 9):

<sup>This is too long to be a comment, since the OP's intent is not 100% clear.</sup>

There is usually very little in terms of interaction between environments used and whatever is contained within them that can be used *outside* of that environment. Typically, environments are used to *format* its contents in a general way, performing certain operations at the start of the environment (at `\begin{<env>}`) and some at the end (at `\end{<env>}`).

If you're interested in performing calculations within your document, or at least mimic it without going through the trouble of specifying things verbatim, the [`fp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) provides floating point operations at compile time. Here is a short example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\newcommand{\degrees}[1][C]{{}^\circ\mathrm{#1}}% degrees celcius/fahrenheit
% Celcius <-> Fahrenheit conversions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit
\begin{document}
Some temperature conversions:
\begin{itemize}
  \item \FPeval{\result}{round((89.2-32)*(5/9),1)}%
    $89.2\degrees[F]=\result\degrees$
  \item \FPeval{\result}{round(25*(9/5)+32,1)}%
    $25\degrees=\result\degrees[F]$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

As a result, it is now possible to include `python` code in your document and you could use inline `fp` code (outside the `python` environment) to calculate expressions that you can typeset in your document.

Comment: I am familiar with the fp package, it is very nice and useful and do use it often ... with python, there are other things I can do (!)

Comment: @Krishnan: Sure. The `python` package and similarly-named `python` environment doesn't allow you to do that. @DJP's answer does something similar to what you're after, only for [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/).

Comment: Another option is to use luatex to get acess to a proper programming language within TeX.

Answer (score 5):

Look for the `pythontex` package on CTAN or gitHub.  It lets you embed python code (including sympy and pyplot code) in your LaTeX document and access the results for typesetting.  You can directly access variable values or have a Python `print` statement generate LaTeX commands.  It handles individual statements (`\py{math.cos(3.14159/4)`} or `\py{"The square root of 2. is {0:3g}".format(math.sqrt(2.))}` or whole blocks of code.  It will also allow code to be typeset with or without execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Pweave](http://mpastell.com/pweave/), which unlike `pythontex` only needs to run once.

Here is [a more complex example that includes localisation.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116282/26348)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Python library [tikzpy](https://tikzpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will allow to do the contrary. Create tikz images via Python

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This question is not the correct place to post this answer. It would be suitable on [tools - How can I use LaTeX from Python. - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/885/how-can-i-use-latex-from-python?noredirect=1&lq=1), however it's recommended to add some examples on how the library should be used to avoid the answer being marked as link-only.

Answer (score 0):

Just to do a bit of advertisement for my `robust-externalize` library, here is a solution. Note that this library is not just made for python, so it might be less specialized than above libraries, but it will be certainly significantly more flexible as it can:

- cache any sort of content, including images (python generated, online…),
- can deal with any language,
- can be used with or without shell-escape for the first compilation (no need to compile twice with shell-escape), no shell-escape needed for later compilations (cached result)
- provide functions to compile in parallel, clean the cache,
- can also get variables from latex via `set placeholder eval={__foo__}{\foo}`.
- print the code next to the result
- automatically run some code (python imports…) if some string are found…
- compilation can be externalized to some servers (say you need GPU access, special libraries…)
- it works on overleaf, arxiv…

If you don't have a recent enough CTAN (needs version v2.7 for the indentation not to cause any issue), just copy the `.sty` file from https://github.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize/ in your project.

### Version 1: just compute some variables in python and reuse them later

It is simpler to compile with `pdflatex --shell-escape document.tex`, but not mandatory, see doc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{robust-externalize}
\robExtConfigure{
  enable fallback to manual mode, % avoid error if shell escape is forgotten/not used, print instead the command in the pdf
}

\begin{document}

\begin{CacheMeCode}{python, do not include pdf}
  import math
  myvalue = math.sqrt(37)
  write_to_out(r"\gdef\myvalue{" + str(myvalue) + r"}")
\end{CacheMeCode}

The value we computed via the above python code is \myvalue.

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version 2: make this into a tiny macro

This library does not provide directly a single macro to do the above in one line (maybe I should provide this option at some points), but it is fairly easy to make one, and you can customize it at will, for instance to wrap your code with some functions automatically, wrap the output with some tikz figures etc:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{robust-externalize}

\robExtConfigure{
  enable fallback to manual mode, % avoid error if shell escape is forgotten/not used, print instead the command in the pdf
  new preset={my python exec}{
    python,
    custom include command={\mytmpvalue},
    add import={import math},
    set placeholder={__ROBEXT_MAIN_CONTENT__}{write_to_out(r"\gdef\mytmpvalue{" + str(__ROBEXT_MAIN_CONTENT_ORIG__)+ r"}")}
  },
}

\begin{document}

You can compute simple values like \cacheMe[my python exec]{math.sqrt(42)}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version 3: include both the code and the result

We provide directly a preset for this (NB: make sure to use v2.8 or above as 2.7 introduces a bug where an empty line is added in front of the code):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{robust-externalize}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\robExtConfigure{
  enable fallback to manual mode, % avoid error if shell escape is forgotten/not used, print instead the command in the pdf
}

\begin{document}

\begin{CacheMeCode}{do not remove leading spaces, python print code and result, set title={The for loop}}
for name in ["Alice", "Bob"]:
    print(f"Hello {name}")
\end{CacheMeCode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version 4: matplotlib images

For a basic pdf-based rendering, you can use the following code, for a more advanced integration with LaTeX with a pgf backend, see my answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/710138/116348

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{robust-externalize}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\robExtConfigure{
  enable fallback to manual mode, % avoid error if shell escape is forgotten/not used, print instead the command in the pdf
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{CacheMeCode}{python, add to includegraphics options={width=\linewidth}}
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib
    year = [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
    tutorial_count = [39, 117, 111, 110, 67, 29]
    plt.plot(year, tutorial_count, color="#6c3376", linewidth=2)
    plt.title("Simple plot")
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Number of futurestud.io Tutorials')
    print(get_filename_from_extension(".pgf"))
    plt.savefig("__ROBEXT_OUTPUT_PDF__")
  \end{CacheMeCode}
  \caption{Test}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]