# Pure Python compiler

Tags: compiling, python, distributions

I am writing a `Python 2.7` program on Windows that generates `LaTeX` output.

I would like to make it able to generate PDF output from the `LaTeX`, but I have only limited leeway to install additional software (I can't install regular `TeX` distributions, but I can install `Python` packages with `pip`).

I would like to know:

- Is there a `LaTeX` compiler in the form of a `Python` package?
- If there is, where can I find it, and how can I use it to compile a `Python` string into a `PDF` file?

The generated `LaTeX` output is meant to be used with the regular `latex` or `pdflatex`.

Comment: No, in reality, only latex can compile latex documents. Note that you generally does not need admin rights to install for example TeXLive.

Comment: If I remember, there is a portable version of MikTeX. Maybe could help you.

Comment: If you are connected to the internet and can use a web browser then [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/), formerly known as Sagemath Cloud, will give you this ability to combine LaTeX with Python via the cloud--no packages to install. See, for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367030/can-we-import-python-file-in-latex/372063#372063).

Comment: There is a Python module to programmatically generate LaTeX documents.  Of course this uses the regular LaTeX executable as a backend. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyLaTeX

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this:

1. let Python create a latex document
2. compile it via the DOS-Cmd shell into a pdf (check Latex doc how to do it)
3. Python can also call shell commands, so just put the previous command into code

Comment: This doesn't really help I think, as the main problem here was that the OP couldn't really install a TeX distribution in the first place, and your method assumes that he already has installed one.

Comment: Right, didn't get it. However, if Phyton install works, why shouldn't a distribution like MikTeX? I can run both. // Then there are remote alternatives, like this one http://aslushnikov.github.io/latex-online/ , self-administrated servers (see google with latex remote compile). // So what's the real problem?

Comment: I don't know more than what's written in the question, but I would think this is not a personal computer, so the OP doesn't have the rights to install any type of software he wants. (Quite common for company computers and the like, I think.) Hence, an answer describing how to use such a remote alternative might very well be helpful, because that would tell the OP a way to circumvent such a limitation.

Comment: @Nathan.Eilisha Shiraini , as you can see there is some confusion about why you can't install a regular *teX distribution. Is it technically, organizational, other? Please let us know :)