# How can I run an .exe in the .tex file?

Tags: pdftex, python

I'm writing a scientific proposal and I have a .exe Python script to copy, timestamp and put into a directory.

I want to use this .exe whenever I compile. From a logic point of view, this would be at the end of the main.tex, but before \end{document}.

Is there a way I can have LaTeX run this .exe?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are ways requiring shell-escape. We already have questions on that topic (search for call external program).

Comment: Search also about "knitr", it was done mainly to run R code in LateX but actually is also able to run python code (without any kind of external script) . See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367030/can-we-import-python-file-in-latex)  for a basic  example.