# Texmaker - Python - Configuration

Tags: texmaker, mac, mactex, python

LaTex friends,
I need your help configuring MacTeX, Texmaker (pdfLatex) and Python on a Mac.

I have received a file where a *.tex uses a Python and I just have no idea how to make this file work.
I already installed Python 3.8 on my Mac, but without much success.

1) Can anyone help me with where and what changes I need to make to control Python from Latex?
2) Do I have to configure Python?
3) Can someone send me a simple code?

I would be really looking forward to an answer, because I am slowly despairing... :(

best regards
George

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367030/can-we-import-python-file-in-latex

Comment: You would need to show enough of the tex from \documentclass to end of preamble and the tex body indicating each type of python call for us to even hazard a guess how it expects to run so it is always best to ask the person who sent you the file what configuration are they using e.g Python2+7 or Python3+8 and with what additional addins