# Is there a way to use LyX like iPython notebooks?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

Is there a way to use LyX like Jupyter/iPython notebooks? To add code fields and get the outputs?

Basically, in an ideal world, I would have a new LyX environment for code. Whenever I execute the code, I get the graphics below. Just like Jupyter/iPython notebooks...

Answer (score 4):

LyX support perfectly "R noweb" literally programming using the module  `Rnw(knitr)` (see en <kbd>Document</kbd> > <kbd>Setttings...</kbd>) that uses the `knitr` package in R for dynamic report generation. Then go to menu <kbd>Insert</kbd> > <kbd>Custom Insets</kbd> > <kbd>S\E expression</kbd> to insert R code inline and <kbd>Chunk</kbd>  to insert a R chunk with options. In LyX screen and the PDF preview  you will see some like this:

> [image: wmw]

In <kbd>Code Preview Pane</kbd>, first input produce a `\Sexpr{2+3}` code, whereas the last will produce:

```
<<fooname,echo=TRUE>>=

2+3; pi+3 # Two sums in R, below the results
@
```

This source is a "R noweb" format to be exported as files with  the `.Rnw` extension, that are basically LaTeX plus this kind  of R code, then call to R to convert it in  pure LaTeX code (the `.tex` version) where the R code is changed by the output (that here is a simple number, but it could be a complete statistical report, or a complex table or a nice plot) and finally, compiled as usual to produce the final PDF.

My advices: (1) know first how it works in the .Rnw files (or .Rtex in Overleaf). I posted about one hundred of [examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A11604+knitr), enough to have a rough idea of the possibilities, but if that is not enough, there are now 340 question in the [knitr tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knitr) and extensive information out there. (2) Use Rstudio or Overleaf to edit and easily compile this files. (3) Once you have caught the concept, use the  LyX module is a child play.

Alternatively, you can use the LyX module `Sweave` for exactly the same: allows to use the statistical language R as a literate programming tool, but via the older and more limited `Sweave()` function. The module suggest you see  `sweave.lyx` for more info.

Finally, for the sake of completeness, `knitr` have also limited support of other languages, as [python](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367208/11604)  there are also a `Noweb` module for literate programming with other languages. There are a [simple example of noweb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noweb#Example_of_a_simple_Noweb_program) in Wikipedia using C, but I have no experience to speak about this module.