# Tikz: addplot error using pythontex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, pythontex

Please, help solve this issue.

The python code have the objective of calculus the derivative of an expression f(x).

If I uncomment the line

```
%\addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=blue ]{\pyc{calc_derivad(func="x^2 + x")}};
```

I've got an error.

But the line

```
\node[draw] at (2,40) {\pyc{calc_derivad(func="x^2 + x")}};
```

doesn't

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}   % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[gobble=auto]{pythontex} % https://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
\addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=blue ]{x^2+x};
\addlegendentry{$x^2 + x$}
\node[draw] at (2,40) {\pyc{calc_derivad(func="x^2 + x")}};
%\addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=blue ]{\pyc{calc_derivad(func="x^2 + x")}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{pythontexcustomcode}{py}
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

def calc_derivad(func):
    func = sympify(func)
    result = diff(func, x)
    print(result, end = '')
    return 0
\end{pythontexcustomcode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not have `pythontex` but I would try `\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot [domain=0:10, samples=100, color=blue ]{\pyc{calc_derivad(func="x^2 + x")}};}\temp`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, thank!


(./pythontex-files-teste02/teste02.pytxmcr)
Package newfloat Info: New float `listing' with options `fileext=lopytx' on inp
ut line 8.
\c@listing=\count153
\newfloat@ftype=\count154
Package newfloat Info: float type `listing'=8 on input line 8.

(./pythontex-files-teste02/teste02.pytxpyg)
! Undefined control sequence.
\pyc ...epythontex {cmd:pyc:ov:p}\xdef \pytx@type 
                                                  {py}\edef \pytx@cmd {c}\py...
l.20 ...\pyc{calc_derivad(func="x^2 + x")}};}\temp
                                                  
? X

Comment: Using `\pyc` within `tikzpicture` inside something like `\node` or `\draw` usually doesn't work. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65294/10742 for some alternatives.