# a good python ambient for my latex code

Tags: listings, code

I am looking for a latex preamble in order to have a good python script. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83882/how-to-highlight-python-syntax-in-latex-listings-lstinputlistings-command) I found this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Default fixed font does not support bold face
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{12} % for bold
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{12}  % for normal

% Custom colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage{listings}

% Python style for highlighting
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
language=Python,
basicstyle=\ttm,
morekeywords={self},              % Add keywords here
keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
emph={MyClass,__init__},          % Custom highlighting
emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
showstringspaces=false
}}


% Python environment
```

which looks great but I find noway to apply it into my latex code, phereaps I'm lost into the complexity of it and what I am looking for is just a sample code such as

```
\begin{document}

here some python codes

\begin{listings}
    \pythonstyle 
import numpy as np
class __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
\end{listings}
\end{document}
```

or the like, in order to have a proper python ambient. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Have a look at `minted` package

Comment: I tried one of that codes. The compiler says: "you must invoke latex with the shell escape flag..." Still issues

Comment: yes, you should use pdflatex -shell-escape FILENAME

Comment: I'm sorry, I still do not understand. Why and how should I do that?

Comment: @StefanoFedele it depends on how you are compiling your document. I use `arara` like this: `arara: pdflatex: {options: -shell-escape}` when I need to shell escape. `Minted` and other packages/programmes (like `makeindex` I believe) require `-shell-escape` to run. Look at `arara` or `latexmk` depending upon what you like, the documentation explains it better then I.

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint. Never heard about this arara

Comment: @StefanoFedele I quite enjoy it, it's a latex package of sorts so should come with a full installation (it did on my windows TeX live anyway). If you look at [my question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/653808/273733) you can see how it is called. It's literally just at the beginning of your `.tex` file, `latexmk` is a good alternative but I prefer `arara`. Hope this helps!

Comment: @StefanoFedele which TeX editor do you use?

Comment: For list the python code but also run it if you want, you may find of interest [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/562438/11604).

Answer (score 3):

You're doing two things wrong:

1. the code environment of the `listings` package is not called `listing`, but `lstlisting`
2. the `\pythonstyle` macro should go *before* the code environment

So if you do

```
\pythonstyle 
\begin{lstlisting}
import numpy as np
class __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
\end{lstlisting}
```

it will work.

I do think it's a bit odd to define a macro like that, instead of for example defining a new listings style with `\lstdefinestyle`. See example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Default fixed font does not support bold face
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{12} % for bold
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{12}  % for normal

% Custom colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage{listings}

% Python style for highlighting
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
language=Python,
literate={-}{-}1 {*}{*}1,% {xxx}{\textrm{   }}1, 
basicstyle=\ttm,
morekeywords={self},              % Add keywords here
keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
emph={MyClass,__init__},          % Custom highlighting
emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
showstringspaces=false
}}

\lstdefinestyle{pythonstyling}{
language=Python,
basicstyle=\ttm,
morekeywords={self},              % Add keywords here
keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
emph={MyClass,__init__},          % Custom highlighting
emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
showstringspaces=false
}


% Python 
\begin{document}
here some python codes

\begin{lstlisting}[style=pythonstyling]
import numpy as np
class __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
\end{lstlisting}

\pythonstyle 
\begin{lstlisting}
import numpy as np
class __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks good, but if you want a pdf with a python code ready to be copied and pasted, than you need to make him understand that a python indentation is present. I tried with that "{xxx}{\textrm{   }}1", but it does not work. Would you suggest anything?

Comment: @StefanoFedele If you set showstringspaces=true that should indicate spaces, but perhaps not what you want?