# How to use sagetex on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, sagetex

I know I can download sagetex package from their website and after taking few steps: installing Sagemath, routing sagetex files to Tex, and etc, I can directly run Sage while writing on my tex (or vice versa?).

But I almost always work on overleaf, so I would like to know how to use sagetex on overleaf.

The thing is I **DO NOT** need to actually run sagemath program; I just need to use commands for formatting such as "\begin{sageblock} \end{sageblock}."

It seems just uploading the distributed files on overleaf and using \usepack{sagemath} wouldn't work. It makes sense cause they were supposed to be used in connection with Sagemath program.

I also know Cocalc supports sagetex and I can work on there, but I just prefer working on Overleaf.

Comment: You can just using the `listings` package and its features to create a new env called `sageblock` that verbatimly shows its contents. See the `listings` manual for more information.

Comment: @daleif yeah, I have heard of that package. It's a good alternative way.

Comment: Independent of this question, if you could spare a few minutes, could you email help@cocalc.com (or make a github issue at https://github.com/sagemathinc/cocalc/issues) and tell us every reason you can think of that you prefer working on Overleaf instead of CoCalc?  It would be extremely helpful for us in improving CoCalc.

Comment: @Andrew Did you find a solution/workaround for this?