# mwrep and pythontex -- is it possible to use

Tags: python, pythontex

The question: possibility of using of working `python` scripts embedded in LaTeX.

When I was using `\usepackage{python}`, it did wonders to my dissertation (although I am very new to LaTeX, but some thousands of lines of code have been written in python). Python was drawing plots and putting them on hard drive, then LaTeX was putting them inside the document. After serious problem with the system (linux Mint), I was forced to reinstall, and `python` + `LaTeX` stopped working. I was looking for a solution and `pythontex` was promising. It turned out, eventually, there is some serious conflict between `mwrep` and `pythontex`.

Is it possible to use `pythontex` with `mwrep`? (`mwrep` is a must *[EDIT: On second thought I don't know if it really is required -- I thought that the printing house wants the document of this class -- to tell the truth I do not know the difference. I'll ask about it the editor.]*)

Or is there a better possibility of emmbeding python scripts inside LaTeX (i.e. working scripts)?

P.S.

I was looking for an answer, but I found no definitive solution.

**UPDATE**

Minimal working example.

*.TEX file:*

```tex
% !TEX options=--shell-escape

\documentclass[11pt]{mwrep}%

\usepackage{pythontex}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{pythontex try}

% \begin{pyconsole}
% x = 987.27
% x = x**2
% print(f"{x = }")
% print("Hello Seba :)")
% \end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

*Sublime Text message:*

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwrepPythontryMini.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwcls/mwrep.cls
Document Class: mwrep 2017/05/13 v0.75 A LaTeX document class (MW)
*** Beta version. Formatting may change
*** in future versions of this class.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwcls/mw11.clo))

(... cut ...)

(./mwrepPythontryMini.aux)
No file pythontex-files-mwrepPythontryMini/mwrepPythontryMini.pytxmcr.
Run PythonTeX to create it.
! Undefined control sequence.
\newfloat@setwithin ...apter}\@chapterlistsgap@on 
                                                  {#1}\newfloat@@setwithin {...
l.9 \begin{document}
                    
?
```

**.sublime-build:*

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "pdflatex $file_name && pythontex $file_name --interpreter python:python3 && pdflatex $file_name && xreader $file_base_name.pdf "
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a MWE (or a minimal non-working example)? I'm not familiar with mwrep...

Comment: There are some other packages listed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33129/250119 as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like some weird interfacing between `newfloat` and `mwrep`. This is my understanding:

- Unlike `article` documentclass, `mwrep` documentclass does not define `\@chapter`.
- This breaks the `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` command for some reason.
- `pythontex` package defines a `listing` environment `\AtBeginDocument` if it's not defined before:

  ```
  \AtBeginDocument{
      \ifcsname listing\endcsname
          \ifbool{pytx@listingenv}{}%
              {\PackageWarning{\pytx@packagename}%
                  {A "listing" environment already exists \MessageBreak
                   \pytx@packagename\space will not create one \MessageBreak
                   Use \string\setpythontexlistingenv\space to create a custom listing environment}}%
      \else
          \ifbool{pytx@listingenv}{}{\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lopytx]{listing}}
      \fi
  }
  ```

You can also reproduce the issue without `newfloat`:

```
\documentclass{mwrep}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{diagram}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

So, apparently a workaround (at least in the current version) is to force pythontex to declare that floating environment
very early on:

```
\RequirePackage{pythontex}
\setpythontexlistingenv{listing}

\documentclass[11pt]{mwrep}%

\begin{document}

\section{pythontex try}

\begin{pyconsole}
x = 987.27
x = x**2
print(f"{x = }")
print("Hello Seba :)")
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

Another workaround is to add

```
\csname @chapter\endcsname
```

to the very start of the document.

Looks like it was caused by some other unrelated change: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/newfloat/-/issues/13

Comment: By the way someone should probably report the issue to the developer https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/newfloat/-/issues ...

Comment: Thank you very much for help, @user202729, I checked also the response by egreg -- both worked for me. I opted for the second reply, the one without the workaround. Now I am struggling with the list of listings -- perhaps you know how to do that with `pythontex`?

Comment: @khaz That's a different question, you should probably ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a dummy definition of `\@chapter`, because `newfloat` uses this macro to distinguish between classes that support chapters and those that don't.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{mwrep}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@chapter{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{pythontex}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{pythontex try}

\begin{pyconsole}
x = 987.27
x = x**2
print(f"{x = }")
print("Hello Seba :)")
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replay, @egreg -- I checked it, and it worked. Perhaps you know how to make a list of listings with `pythontex`?