# Generating reports with LaTeX programmatically

Tags: automation, report

[Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_reports), [JasperReports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports) and many other report writers are conventionally used in software development practices when it comes to producing printer-ready reports.

It would appear that a LaTeX based template engine could be successfully used instead to produce such reports. This could be especially convenient for software houses well familiar with LaTeX (e.g. where it is used to produce technical and other documentation).

Had anyone heard of any effort in this direction? Some FOSS project?

Comment: See the latest TeX.sx blog entry! http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/generating-latex-code-with-a-template-engine/

Comment: Yes... it must in the air (:

Comment: In the past I have used awk or Perl to generate LaTeX source code and then run the reports.  I was generating individual grade sheet reports for students from my grades database.   More recently I have generated statistical analyses using LaTeX and R with the Sweave package for R.  (a new package knitr is available and has some very nice additional features, but I have not used it yet)

Comment: For Python libraries in particular, see [tools - How can I use LaTeX from Python. - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/885/how-can-i-use-latex-from-python?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2):

With `knitr` there is a new player on the field which tries to overcome a few of Sweave's limitations. Find more information at https://github.com/yihui/knitr

Answer (score 1):

I frequently use Latex alongside [R](http://www.r-project.org) and [Sweave](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leisch/Sweave/) to generate reports in data mining and ETL type projects.  It works well and produces professional looking output.